# Is a woman obligated to attend her husband's funeral?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya

An elderly woman cares for her sick husband for many years with great devotion until she can't do it anymore and has to put him in a nursing home. Her children convince her to take a long cruise to recuperate. A few days into the cruise the husband dies.  The children try to convince her to complete the cruise and skip the funeral.

Is the decision at her own discretion or is she halachically obligated to do one or the other?

(The high cost of a cruise and her need to recuperate are factors.)

Comment: See Nitei Gavriel 67:7 &  Michaber 359:1

Comment: Could you quote them?

Comment: The Mitzva is to bury the deceased ASAP. Rarely, historically, would anyone travel to a funeral.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- still, there is the matter of her returning to sit Shiva.

Comment: @Mau No such thing. Shiva can be sat anywhere.

Comment: @DoubleAA. What's the point of sitting shiva in a place far from home where nobody knows you, when you have the option of going home?

Comment: @Maurice The point of shiva is not to entertain visitors. The point of Shiva is to honor the deceased. Probably someone alone on a cruise ship would be yotzeh their mitzvah better than having the open house circus that is the modern shiva house.

Comment: Are we discussing sitting shiva or  attending a funeral?

Comment: Can you focuse on one question, with arguments for positive answer and arguments for negative answer, and people can try to understand and answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

1. There's only one funeral-related Rabbinical obligation, and it is for the husband *to fund* the burial for his wife. Not even participate. This is a monetary obligation, not moral or  (Rambam Ishus 22)
2. There are no obligations on the wife's side toward her husband's funeral - neither monetary or moral. No moral ones because Judaism generally does not intervene with couple's relations and no monetary obligations because she becomes instantly and formally "divorced" with his death (קונה את עצמה במיתת הבעל - Kidd 1,1).

   Clarification: she still mourns DeRabanan (the Shiv'ah) but it's not between her and her husband - it's between her and G-d.

   Also it's a far bigger Mitzvah DeOrayso for the kids to take care of and attend the funeral of their father.
3. The funeral is considered a Chessed Shel Emes (a branch of Gmilus Chassadim) and it is a big positive Mitzvah on its own which however cannot be forced to do (a Beis Din can not force a wife to care for her husband's funeral).

Comment: This is at best a gross oversimplification that implies things which are clearly false. For example, your number 2 implies that's a wife doesn't sit Shiva when her husband passes away. Whether or not that's what you meant, it's clearly not true and highly misleading.

Comment: @Salmononius2 What exactly is *"it's clearly not true and highly misleading"*? Let's go one by one.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, your bullet point number 2 implies that a woman does not sit Shiva for her husband.

Comment: @Salmononius2 DId I say that? You made it up and blame me for not being true. What's Halachicly wrong with my answer? Also for all -1 voters.

Comment: You did not say that, but that's what your answer _implies_.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by explaining what it means for the wife to be "free with his death" as well as specifically addressing whether she is obligated in sitting Shiva as well

Comment: @Dude Better now?

Comment: Apparently, in a number of Hassidic customs. no women are allowed at the cemetery during burial. Thus, if there is a graveside "funeral", the wife does not attend. I have heard of some customs where the wife will be in a separate room in the funeral prior to the funeral ceremony. However, she remains in that room during the funeral, as she is not allowed to be at the funeral. I have no idea of the reasoning to the minhag. I'm surmising that one factor may be the lack of a mechitza (I don't think it's required.) in the funeral home, as there were no women at all attending the funeral I was in.

Comment: #1 is wrong. Rambam Aveilus 2:7 #2 is wrong both as a categorical statement and in the specifics. Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer is full of interference, and she is obligated to morn for him (see Ramabam Aveilus 2:1) #3 is wrong as well as a general statement. There are many positive commandments which one can be forced to do, including מת מצוה.

Comment: @Yishai Please be specific, #1 what's exactly learned from Avelus 2,7? #2 I hold that Hilchos Aveilus are not interpersonal at all. For example Avelus after one's father has nothing to do with Kibud Av. Similarly for a wife - it's between her and G-d, her obligation TOWARD G-d, not the husband. 3. What non-monetary Chessed a person can be forced to? Please provide examples

Comment: @AlBerko, #1 an obligation to attend to the מת, not just pay for it, and it begins to show the moral parameters of the matter #2, (Kibud Av may not be interpersonal, but) if she is obligated to mourn then she can be obligated in other practices of honoring the deceased. #3, I read your statement as being categorically about positive commandments, but an example of a non-monetary chesed one is obligated to perform is a מת מצוה. Your conclusion may or may not be right (you can do most such things through a shliach, after all), but your arguments for getting there seem wrong.

Comment: @Yishai Your "seem wrong" sound more convincing than plain "you're wrong" :) #1 where do you learn an obligation for the husband to attend his wife's funeral? #2 you say "CAN be obligated", meaning you understand she's not. Her husband could be abusive of dumb or else. A woman has no "obligation" of post-mortem respect for her husband (I didn't say she shouldn't). Please prove me wrong. #3 do we force on מת מצווה? I don't know I didn't hear anything about it. But I'm sure we can't force a widow to take care of her husband's funeral.

Comment: @Yishai I also added: " Also it's a far bigger Mitzvah DeOrayso for the kids to take care of and attend the funeral of their father."

Comment: @AlBerko, #1 what do you think that Halacha is saying? #2, What you are basically saying is she has no priority in obligation to bury her husband and is the equivalent of a stranger. But all you do is assert that while making incorrect categorical statements that are the opposite of explicit sources. (If others i.e. the children come first or she can send a shliach is not the same as your assertion that she has no obligation) #3 S.A. Y.D. 374:3